# Casting Java reference to method returning value to one returning `void`

Tags: java, casting, method-reference

The JLS casting rules seem pretty intricate on this point: Is it correct to cast a reference to a method returning some value to a reference accepting the same argument types but returning `void`? I *think* it's okay because `void` is narrower than any type.

For example...

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class MethodRefCaster {

  /** Operation accepting and returning Integer. */
  Integer fooOp(Integer x) {
    System.out.println(x);
    return x + 3;
  }

  /** Applier of given op accepting Integer, returning void. */
  void applyOpToBar(Consumer<Integer> op, int bar) {
    op.accept(bar);
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    MethodRefCaster x = new MethodRefCaster();

    // Cast the method ref to make it fit.
    x.applyOpToBar((Consumer<Integer>) x::fooOp, 42);
  }
}
```

This prints 42 as you might expect. But is it correct Java? Many thanks.

Comment: I expected it to fail because `Consumer<Integer>` is not the same as `IntConsumer`, despite the casting.

Comment: Well it works, but I didn't mean to confuse the issue so will change the op to Integer -> Integer. Thanks.

Comment: In fact, I'd leave it as is because it's really interesting that it doesn't fail.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Perhaps, but I thought that the advantage of IntConsumer was just preventing unboxing.

Comment: I'll do more research about it on my own (your original code ignited my curiosity).

Comment: I'm not sure Java cares what the return type is, until run time when it tries to take the return value and shove it into a reference to the return type.   Return types are not part of a Java signature when determining uniqueness, which is why vagueness can occur.